# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a particular piece of a website. I'm hoping to get to:

```
 <div class="inhoudsindicatie"><p><span class="hl0 highlightColor0">HR</span>: art. 81RO.</p></div>
```

and in particular the "art. 81RO" part of it.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
 driver.get('http://uitspraken.rechtspraak.nl/inziendocument?id=ECLI:NL:HR:2014:3004&showbutton=true&keyword=HR%3a')
 page=soup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
 details=soup.findAll("span",{"class":"hl0 highlightColor0"})
```

It returns:

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'
```

What does this imply about my code ? I read the general information on descendants and I am quite sure I don't understand.

(My main interest is in understanding the problem, solving it is secondary, though of course highly appreciated)

Comment: You forgot to define your dirver, eg : `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: Why dont you try with urllib2 or requests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get('http://uitspraken.rechtspraak.nl/inziendocument?id=ECLI:NL:HR:2014:3004&showbutton=true&keyword=HR%3a')
time.sleep(5)
page = soup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
details = page.select_one("span.hl0.highlightColor0").find_parent().get_text()
print(details)
driver.quit()

# output: HR: art. 81RO.
```

But since you're using selenium anyway, why not just stick with it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get('http://uitspraken.rechtspraak.nl/inziendocument?id=ECLI:NL:HR:2014:3004&showbutton=true&keyword=HR%3a')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
xpath = "//p/span[contains(@class, 'highlightColor0') and contains(@class, 'hl0')]/.."
details = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
print(details.text)
driver.quit()

# output: HR: art. 81RO.
```

If you don't want the 'HR:' part you can remove it:

```
details.split('HR: ')[1]

# output: art. 81RO.
```