# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants' error when using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**@ayivima has a great answer down there, but I should add that the website itself ended up being not **scraped** properly by BeautifulSoup as it had a ton of Javascript.**

---

So I'm utterly new at using Python, and I'm just trying to print the title of a webpage. I'm using this code mostly from google:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=3210001601"
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup
soup.find_all('h1')

print(text)
```

And I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'
```

and I honestly don't really have a clue as to what it means, the only other answer I can find is from: [AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235821/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-descendants) which I don't think applies to me?

Anything I'm doing wrong in the code? (A lot, probably, but I mean mostly for this error)

Comment: Where is the `text` field defined?

Comment: oh, i thought that was part of the command. even after adding ```text = soup.get_text()
``` i still get the same error

Comment: First, why there is no instance of Soup? `soup = BeautifulSoup` doesn't create one. Secondly, where are you initializing text?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: err, let me look around, not sure what an instance of Soup is, reading through their page right now. I did add ```text = soup.get_text()``` which I assume is what @FarhoodET means by initialing text. I have no clue what complete traceback is, but I'm looking into it, @wwii

Comment: @wwii I have, but then i get the error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/TitleSraping/venv/Text Scraping.py", line 8, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
  File "D:\Python\TitleSraping\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 245, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()```

Comment: Try `soup = BeautifulSoup(data)` - [Making the soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)

Comment: @wwii it seems to have worked, but now I get a ton of stuff, not sure if it's from Soup or if I'm using it wrong. Thanks though

Answer (score 5):

BeautifulSoup requires that an html parser, and the html text is passed as attributes. Technically, you need to create an instance of BeautifulSoup. If you don't pass the html text, there will be nothing to search through.

So the line `soup = BeautifulSoup` must become something like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
```

where the first parameter, in this case `data` refers to the raw html text, and the second parameter is the parser, `html.parser`. I am using the default python html parser, but python supports other parsers aside. Find out more here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/.

RECOMMENDED CODE:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=3210001601"
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all('h1')

print(text)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

It appears BeautifulSoup didn't find any `h1` tag.

Let's experiment with `meta` tags:

```
meta_tags = soup.find_all('meta')
print(meta_tags)
```

Output:

```
[<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma"/>, 
<meta content="-1" http-equiv="Expires"/>, 
<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="CacheControl"/>]
```

Comment: Ahh, okay, that's why the code I was testing on my side wasn't working, i was using double quotes with my `html.parser` thank you so much.  But it seems like i can't get it to work when looking for ```h1```

Comment: The problem is not really the double quotes. It should still work. BeautifulSoup couldn't catch the h1 tag. But it works for the meta tags, as demonstrated in my edit :)

Comment: Yeah, i think that's probably it, not sure how I'm supposed to find the title then, since I can see in the Chrome html elements in that page that the title is in h1, not sure how it works in BeautifulSoup though, or maybe I'm understanding the console wrong

Comment: Yes, I inspected the html as well and I saw a NEWLINE separating the opening tag from the rest of the tag for the h1. This may have caused the detection problem. You might want to use regular expressions to pick out the h1, if you really need it.

Comment: I'll try that out, thank you so much for the help. I'm really new to all of this

Comment: Thats ok :). Just keep at it... :)